# Finding solution of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the solutions of this trigonometric equation $$\sum_{m=1}^6 cosec(\theta + \frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}) cosec(\theta + \frac{m\pi}{4}) =4\sqrt{2}$$ if $0<\theta<\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$\csc\left(\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4\right)\cdot\csc\left(\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4\right)=\dfrac1{\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4\right)\cdot\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4\right)}$

$\dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin A\sin B}=\dfrac{\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B}{\sin A\sin B}=\cot B-\cot A$

Here $A=\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4$  and $B=\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4, A-B=\dfrac\pi4$

$\implies\dfrac1{\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4\right)\cdot\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4\right)}$

$=\dfrac1{\sin\dfrac\pi4}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\left\{\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4-\left(\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4\right)\right\}}{\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4\right)\cdot\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4\right)}$

$=\dfrac{\cot\left(\theta+\dfrac{(m-1)\pi}4\right)-\cot\left(\theta+\dfrac{m\pi}4\right)}{\sin\dfrac\pi4}$

Set $m=1,2,3,4,5,6$ and add and finally simplify.

Comment: @ResearchEngineer, Could u follow the hint?

Comment: @ResearchEngineer, put $m=1$ to $6$ to identify the surviving terms.

Comment: @ResearchEngineer, Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @ResearchEngineer, If $$f(m)=g(m-1)-g(m),$$ can you prove $$\sum_{m=1}^n f(m)=g(0)-g(n)$$ for integer $n\ge1$